# How to generate list indices with format directives

Tags: formatting, lisp, common-lisp

Is there a way to get the same output as this:
(Hand is a list of cards)

```
(loop for card in hand
           with i = 1
           do
             (format t "~&~a. ~a~%" i card)
             (incf i))
```

```
1. (5 . HEARTS)
2. (5 . CLUBS)
3. (10 . DIAMONDS)
4. (JACK . DIAMONDS)
5. (8 . CLUBS)
```

but only using one call to format? So far I have this, but I have no idea how to increment the index.

```
(format nil "~{~%1. ~a~}~%" hand)
```

```
1. (5 . HEARTS)
1. (5 . CLUBS)
1. (10 . DIAMONDS)
1. (JACK . DIAMONDS)
1. (8 . CLUBS)
```

I also tried using a closure alongside the Call Function directive, but you have to reset the counter for every call, and it just feels very kludgey.

```
(let ((counter 0))
  (defun increment (output-stream format-argument colonp at-sign-p &rest directive-parameters)
    (declare (ignore colonp at-sign-p directive-parameters))
    (incf counter)
    (format output-stream "~a. ~a" counter format-argument))
  (defun reset-counter ()
    (setf counter 0)))

(format t "~&~{~&~/increment/~}" '(a c b d))
```

```
1. A
2. C
3. B
4. D
```

Comment: I think that, while you can really do anything by getting `format` to call functions for you, there are cases where the answer is just not to do that.  Something like Rainer's `numbering` function is what I'd do: code using it reads nicely I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to me is to loop here. The function I would write is:

```
(defun format-hand (stream hand)
  (loop
     with width = (ceiling (log (length hand) 10))
     for index from 1
     for (value . color) in hand
     do (format stream "~&~vd. ~@(~a~) of ~(~a~)" width index value color)))
```

The `width` part can be omitted if you know the hand never contains more than 9 cards. It is used to align indices in the formatted output. For example, with a very long hand:

```
(let ((hand '((5 . hearts) (5 . clubs) (10 . diamonds) 
              (jack . diamonds) (8 . clubs))))
  (format-hand t (concatenate 'list hand hand hand hand)))

 1. 5 of hearts
 2. 5 of clubs
 3. 10 of diamonds
 4. Jack of diamonds
 5. 8 of clubs
 6. 5 of hearts
 7. 5 of clubs
 8. 10 of diamonds
 9. Jack of diamonds
10. 8 of clubs
11. 5 of hearts
12. 5 of clubs
13. 10 of diamonds
14. Jack of diamonds
15. 8 of clubs
16. 5 of hearts
17. 5 of clubs
18. 10 of diamonds
19. Jack of diamonds
20. 8 of clubs
```

Another example with fancy unicode symbols (see [`GETF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_getf.htm)):

```
(defun format-hand (stream hand)
  (loop
     with width = (ceiling (log (length hand) 10))
     for index from 1
     for (value . color) in hand
     for symbol = (getf '(hearts "♥" diamonds "♦" spades "♠" clubs "♣") color)
     do (format stream "~&~vd. ~a ~a" width index symbol value)))

(format-hand t '((5 . hearts) (5 . clubs) (10 . diamonds)
               (jack . diamonds) (8 . clubs)))

1. ♥ 5
2. ♣ 5
3. ♦ 10
4. ♦ JACK
5. ♣ 8
```

Answer (score 8):

Your loop form:

```
(loop for card in hand
           with i = 1
           do
             (format t "~&~a. ~a~%" i card)
             (incf i))
```

One usually would write that as:

```
(loop for card in hand and i from 1
      do (format t "~&~a. ~a~%" i card))
```

One way to simply deal with the problem is to provide a list with numbers:

```
(defun numbering (list &key (i0 1))
  (loop for i from i0 and element in list
        collect i collect element))

CL-USER > (format t "~{~%~a. ~a~}~%" (numbering hand))

1. (5 . HEARTS)
2. (5 . CLUBS)
3. (10 . DIAMONDS)
4. (JACK . DIAMONDS)
5. (8 . CLUBS)
NIL
```